# Style radio input with css or jquery

Tags: css, jquery-ui, input, radio-button

I'm trying to make the two arrows that show in my range slider picture. I think the logic way to do this is to make an input type:radio , because just one of them can be checked at the same time. But my question is if I could style the input radio to look like an arrow. Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: The only reson to use a input:radio would be if you like to save data with a regular html-form. Otherwise you could use a javascript variable and just toggle two images.

Comment: The functionality of those two arrows is just to order results already given. If you click on the upper arrow the results will be ordered from highest bid values to less bid values and if you click the down arrow teh results will be ordered from less bid values to highest bid values. I hope to have been clear enough. My problem is that I don't know how to style those inputs to look like an arrow.

Comment: I would recommend not to use a input with type=radio at all. Just use an image and add click-events with jquery